# FancyBox scrolling parent page's content too

Tags: javascript, scroll, fancybox, fancybox-2

Using FancyBox v2.0.6 with or without the mousewheel plugin. If the user opens FancyBox, scrolls to the end of the content and then continues scrolling, the parent page will then scroll.

This can be disconcerting, for when the user closes FancyBox, they are not at the same location on the parent page.

Is there a way to stop the parent page from scrolling when FancyBox is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try adding these fancybox options to your custom script

```
beforeLoad: function(){
 $("body").css({"overflow-y":"hidden"});
},
afterClose: function(){
 $("body").css({"overflow-y":"visible"});
}
```

... so basically it stops the vertical scrolling on the parent page while fancybox is open.